# "NoSuchMethodError" when initialising object from pthread

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have an Android/Java application which calls down to C++ code through JNI to start a blocking operation. The C++ code starts a thread to do this blocking operation which should then call back through JNI when it's finished.

Calling down to C++ works without any issues. However, when calling back to JNI a mix of error's are being reported.

Getting a `jclass` reference from a new thread is apparently not legal. Performing that action gives "unpredictable behaviour" so all class lookup's are being performed in the `JNI_OnLoad()` method and look like this:

```
static jclass sampleClazz;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved)
{
    jvm = vm;

    JNIEnv* env = NULL;
    jint result = jvm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    if(env == NULL) { __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "JNI_OnLoad", "NULL");}

    sampleClazz= env->FindClass("com/sample/SampleClazz");
    sampleClazz= (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(sampleClazz);

    ...etc...
}
```

In one of these threads I'm trying to call back to the Java code. The callback method looks similar to this:

```
void cCallBackOne() {
    JNIEnv* env;
    jvm->AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon(&env, NULL);

    jmethodID init = env->GetMethodID(sampleClazz, "<init>", "()V");
    if(init == NULL) { 
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "START", "NULL HERE"); 
    } else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "START", "ALL FINE"); 
    }
```

Unfortunately for some unknown reason this is logging/throwing:

```
Exception Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError; thrown while initializing Lcom/sample/SampleClazz;
NULL HERE
```

While working through different solution's I tried moving the `GetMethodId` to the `JNI_OnLoad` method in order to see if I could correctly pull the method reference from the original Java thread. It works fine... But strangely, once I do this ***The code inside the callback also begins to work***.

I'm massively stumped. I have no idea what is going on and am not sure what to try next.

Comment: Not exactly related, but if you block, why do you start a thread ? It sounds like you could do the job in the same thread ...

Comment: Have you tried creating the thread in Java? That's what I do for blocking operations and they work fine. Then there's no need to mess with the problematic C to Java callback mechanism.

Comment: I can confirm, I'm doing what I'm doing for a good reason.

Comment: This is probably just a typo, but shouldn't `sampleClazz` in the callback be `stringClazz` (the one defined in `JNI_OnLoad`?

Comment: Note the elipses in JNI_OnLoad. Will change it for clarity now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I've put it down to an error being thrown elsewhere and this being a symptom of just such a problem. I have created these set of methods and am now using `check()` after each of my calls:

```
void check(jclass toCheck) {
    if(toCheck == NULL) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Check", "Error retrieving jclass");
    }
}

void check(jmethodID toCheck) {
    if(toCheck == NULL) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Check", "Error retrieving jmethodID");
    }
}

void check(jfieldID toCheck) {
    if(toCheck == NULL) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Check", "Error retrieving jfieldID");
    }
}

void check(jobject toCheck) {
    if(toCheck == NULL) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Check", "Error retrieving jobject");
    }
}
```

Just adding these checks have so far solved my issue... For the sake of sanity I hope there is a reason other than "magic" to explain why this is...

I'm afraid though I'm going to have to admit there was some strange exception being thrown earlier in the code execution and this was simply a symptom of an earlier crash.

The lesson: Remember to insulate your code people! If JNI crashes it keep's it to itself and something down the road will break instead.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was ages ago but, I've just had the same problem. I found that my Java class was not used in any Java code, therefore it was being optimized out. I used the Java class in my app and it all now works from the C side of things.